# Is their a way to output to a panel in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I am relatively new to JSF. I am trying to display data into a web page sorta like a jTextArea or at least onto a panel that is on the webpage, something similar to that. I can display the data in a particular format but it won't appear onto a panel in a specific location or the panel being a particular setSize. Can someone point me into the right direction of what I need to learn in order to do this. The simpler the better as I believe in simplicity.

Comment: Please specify your question and use web-related terms, you're not using Swing, it's a web related framework. Moreover, if you're new at SO, you should know it's better to post tested code in your questions.

Comment: So you got text you want to display on a page and constrain that to a specific dimension? Sounds like you need to realize that jsf just builds HTML (however fancy the creation process looks). And you can style this with CSS. No need for black magic, `position`, `width`, `height` CSS attributes are your friends.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputTextarea.jsf)

Comment: Yeh about two months later I realize that CSS and AJAX are powerful tools. CSS being used in all websites developed today.

Comment: @Xtreme you are right, I should just use web-related terms and leave java out because not everyone uses java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Primefaces` provides you many forms to display data: `dataGrid`, `carousel`,... you should use pimefaces showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf .

Comment: Do you find JSF powerful and useful for web application development?

Comment: this UI librairy  provides all components that i need for a JEE application development with ease of use, simplicity and performance.